# Replicating a xml namespace node using groovy script

Tags: groovy, automation, soapui

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/appliance/management/3.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:QuiesceRequest>
         <ns:Domain>
            <ns:Name></ns:Name>
            <ns:Timeout></ns:Timeout>
              <ns:Services>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <ns:Object name="" class-name="" class-display-name=""/>
               enter tag here
               enter tag here
               enter tag here
              </ns:Services>
         </ns:Domain>
      </ns:QuiesceRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

I have a requirement to add below tag multiple times :

tag to be added=>

```
 ns:Object name="" class-name="" class-display-name=""
```

## Similar to the tag shown above "enter tag here"

## inside above XML:

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this in the groovy script?

I have tried a few scripts but the desired result is not achieved.

Comment: please edit your question and provide script that you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what were the scripts, that didn't work. You can simply set groovy response under the whole ns:Services tag, within the script adding necessary amount of nodes with loop to groovy return object, something like this:

```
<ns:Services>${SomeGroovyScript#result}</ns:Services>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I Just did with the set and get property method. Appreciate your contribution